# How to find all referrers of an object in Java?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm

We have a memory leak problem, we don't know what/where too many instances of a certain class are created/referred from. This occurs under heavy load in production and we cannot obtain heap dump (taking heap dump hangs the HA server for too long time). Runtime profiling is also not an option on production site because of performance degradation, the customers are happier with a random crash rather than agonizing slow during monitoring trying to fish for the crash instant. We don't know how to initiate the crash (leak), it just occurs at some times.

Is there a way to obtain object referrers/instantiation points at runtime from within the application itself?

I looked at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ObjectReference.html and it gives an idea that something like this could be possible.

Any pointers how to achieve this preferrably with custom code without the heap-dump-way? Reproducing the problem in test environment has been tried and it seems exhaustive wild goose-chase. We want now a brute force way to find the cause.

Comment: Instead of trying to work around the heap dump taking too long, try concentrating your efforts on reproducing the problem in a test environment. Look at tools like JMeter for scaling up the load.

Comment: Reproducing the problem in test environment has been tried and it seems exhaustive. We want now a brute force way to find the cause.

Comment: I've never done anything like that, and maybe this is a silly idea, but could it be an option to log client requests/application operations, for later replication on a test site?

Comment: Hmm.. logging requests also sounds like needle in haystacks x wild goose chaese. We are currently considering collecting stacktraces on instantiation and on clone.. and dumping them when memory goes low. We know the Object class that causes the problem, just need to hunt down where it is born.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the issue by collecting stacktraces on instantiation and on clone.. and by dumping them on a scheduler and when memory goes low.

We know the Object class that causes the problem, just needed to hunt down where it is born:

```
@EntityListeners(AbstractDTOJpaEventListener.class)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractDTO implements Storeable, Serializable, Cloneable {
  /** */
  private static final String SHADOWED_CLASS = "Custom";
  /** */
  protected final static boolean DEBUG_CUSTOM_INSTANCES = true;
  /** */
  public static long TARGET_HITRATE_PER_INTERVAL = 400000;
  /** */
  public static long LOGGING_INTERVAL = Times.MILLISECONDS_IN_TEN_SECONDS;
  /** */
  private static long previousLoggingTime;
  /** */
  protected static int hits;
  /** */
  protected static boolean hitting;
  /** */
  protected static int hitsWithinInterval;

  /**
   * @author Martin
   */
  public static class Hi {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private long hitted;
    private final long createdAt;
    private final StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements;
    private final String threadName;

    /**
     * @param threadName 
     * @param stackTraceElements 
     */
    public Hi(String threadName, StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements) {
      this.threadName = threadName;
      this.createdAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
      this.stackTraceElements = stackTraceElements;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public void hit() {
      hitted++;
    }

    /**
     * @return the hitted
     */
    public long getHitted() {
      return hitted;
    }

    /**
     * @param hitted the hitted to set
     */
    public void setHitted(long hitted) {
      this.hitted = hitted;
    }

    /**
     * @return the createdAt
     */
    public long getCreatedAt() {
      return createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @return the stackTraceElements
     */
    public StackTraceElement[] getStackTraceElements() {
      return stackTraceElements;
    }

    /**
     * @return the threadName
     */
    public String getThreadName() {
      return threadName;
    }
  }

  /** */
  protected final static Map<String, Hi> INSTANCE_SHADOW = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Hi>();

  private static final Comparator<? super Entry<String, Hi>> COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Entry<String, Hi>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, Hi> o1, Entry<String, Hi> o2) {
      if (o1 == o2) {
        return 0;
      }

      return -Utils.compareNullSafe(o1.getValue().getHitted(), o2.getValue().getHitted(), Compare.ARG0_FIRST);
    }
  };

  /**
   * @param <T> 
   * @return T
   * @see java.lang.Object#clone()
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public <T extends AbstractDTO> T clone() {
    try {
      return (T) super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
      if (DEBUG_CUSTOM_INSTANCES && getClass().getSimpleName().equals(SHADOWED_CLASS)) {
        shadowInstance();
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * 
   */
  protected void shadowInstance() {
    if (DEBUG_CUSTOM_INSTANCES) {
      final long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

      if (TARGET_HITRATE_PER_INTERVAL <= ++hitsWithinInterval) {
        hitting = true;
      }

      if ((TARGET_HITRATE_PER_INTERVAL / 2) <= ++hits) {
        final Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();

        final StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = currentThread.getStackTrace();

        final String key = Utils.getPropertyPath(String.valueOf(System.identityHashCode(currentThread)), displayStackLocaktion(stackTrace))
            .intern();

        Hi hi = INSTANCE_SHADOW.get(key);

        if (hi == null) {
          synchronized (key) {
            hi = INSTANCE_SHADOW.get(key);

            if (hi == null) {
              INSTANCE_SHADOW.put(key, hi = new Hi(currentThread.getName(), stackTrace));
            }

          }
        }

        hi.hit();
      }

      {
        if (getLoggingInterval(currentTimeMillis) != getLoggingInterval(previousLoggingTime)) {
          if (hitsWithinInterval < TARGET_HITRATE_PER_INTERVAL) {
            if (hitting) {
              hitting = false;
            } else {
              hits = 0; // Reset measuring on second round, give chance to burtsy hits
            }
          }

          hitsWithinInterval = 0;
          previousLoggingTime = currentTimeMillis;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * @param time
   * @return long
   */
  private long getLoggingInterval(long time) {
    return time / LOGGING_INTERVAL;
  }

  /**
   * @return String
   */
  public static String toStringShadows() {
    final ArrayList<Entry<String, Hi>> entries;

    synchronized (INSTANCE_SHADOW) {
      entries = Convert.toMinimumArrayList(INSTANCE_SHADOW.entrySet());
      INSTANCE_SHADOW.clear();
    }

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) + " " + SHADOWED_CLASS + " Class instance instantiantion summary:\n");
    stringBuilder.append("hits=" + hits + ", hitting=" + hitting + ", hitsWithinInterval=" + hitsWithinInterval + ", previousLoggingTime=" + new java.sql.Timestamp(previousLoggingTime));

    if (entries.isEmpty()) {
      return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    Collections.sort(entries, COMPARATOR);

    int index = 0;
    stringBuilder.append("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");

    for (Entry<String, Hi> entry : entries) {
      Utils.append(stringBuilder, entry.getValue().getHitted() + "\t" + entry.getKey(), "\n");
    }

    for (Entry<String, Hi> entry : entries) {
      final Hi hi = entry.getValue();
      final StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = hi.getStackTraceElements();
      final String groupName = entry.getKey();

      final String threadName = hi.getThreadName();

      stringBuilder.append("\n").append(++index).append('\t');
      stringBuilder.append(hi.getHitted()).append("\tpcs\t").append(groupName);
      stringBuilder.append("\t").append(new Timestamp(hi.getCreatedAt()).toString()).append('\t').append(threadName)
          .append('\t').append(Convert.toString(stackTrace));
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
  }

  /**
   * @param stackTrace
   * @return String
   */
  private static String displayStackLocaktion(final StackTraceElement[] stackTrace) {
    StackTraceElement firstDistinguishingStackTraceElement = null;

    for (int index = 0; index < stackTrace.length; index++) {
      firstDistinguishingStackTraceElement = stackTrace[index];
      if (!Arrays.asList(UNWANTED_LOCATIONS).contains(firstDistinguishingStackTraceElement.getClassName())) {
        break;
      }
    }

    StackTraceElement lastDistinguishingStackTraceElement = null;

    for (int index = stackTrace.length-1; 0 <= index; index--) {
      lastDistinguishingStackTraceElement = stackTrace[index];
      if (lastDistinguishingStackTraceElement.getClassName().startsWith(OUR_PACKAGE_DOMAIN)) {
        break;
      }
    }

    return Utils.getPropertyPath(displayName(firstDistinguishingStackTraceElement) + "<-"
        + displayName(lastDistinguishingStackTraceElement));
  }

  /**
   * @param firstDistinguishingStackTraceElement
   * @return String
   */
  private static String displayName(StackTraceElement firstDistinguishingStackTraceElement) {
    return Utils.getPropertyPath(firstDistinguishingStackTraceElement.getClassName(), firstDistinguishingStackTraceElement.getMethodName(),
        String.valueOf(firstDistinguishingStackTraceElement.getLineNumber()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Also a native way to do this exists via Java agent: https://code.google.com/p/java-allocation-instrumenter/

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended that you try to check you code which is causing such leaks. Here are some tutorials and help regarding the same

IBM Article on Handling memory leaks in Java
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-leaks/

Some other useful articles
http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188158/How-to-Fix-Memory-Leaks-in-Java

There is also an [Eclipse Memory Analyser Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

But the most recommended solution will be 
Try running [`jvisualvm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) from the JVM on the same machine as your program is running and enable profiling.

Comment: Runtime profiling is also not an option on production site because of performance degradation, the customers are happier with a random crash rather than agonizing slow during monitoring trying to fish for the crash instant. We don't know how to initiate the crash (leak), it just occurs at some times.

Comment: You should never try to profile on a live production system. Instead try to profile before it is deployed on a test system and fix the leak issues.

Comment: We do not know how to reproduce the problem in test environment, otherwise we would have fixed this long time ago.

Comment: I can understand your situation... you want some flags that can be put through the application server which will perform better garbage collection ... for this you I found a sun presentation regarding the same http://weblogs.java.net/blog/gsporar/archive/files/2417.pdf but it talks about some basic flags only.. which I hope you must have already applied.

Comment: We are currently considering collecting stacktraces on instantiation and on clone.. and dumping them when memory goes low.